# Add a column in second DataFrame based on 2 matched column in 2 DataFrame

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have 2 DataFrame, I want to add a column in second DataFrame based on multiple (In my case 2) matched column of both DataFrame
I tried the code below, but I don't get the right answer. Can anyone help me please?

```
result = result.merge(out[out['COL1.']!=''].drop(['month'], axis=1), on=['COL1.'], how='left').merge(out[out['month']!=''].drop(['COL1.'], axis=1), on=['month'], how='left')
```

df1:

```
    COL1.       count   month
1   Plassen     1293    4
2   Adamstuen   567     4
3   AHO.        1799    5
4   Akersgata   2418    4
```

df2 :

```
    station     month
1   Plassen     4
2   Adamstuen   4
3   AHO.        5
4   Akersgata.  6
```

What I want is :

```
    station     month.  count 
1   Plassen     4.       1293
2   Adamstuen   4.       567
3   AHO.        5.       1799
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `merge()` method and chain `drop()` method to it:

```
result=df2.merge(df1,right_on=['COL1.','month'],left_on=['station','month']).drop(columns=['COL1.'])
```

Now if you print `result` you will get your desired output:

```
    station     month   count
0   Plassen     4       1293
1   Adamstuen   4       567
2   AHO.        5       1799
```

Answer (score 0):

In this case,`df.join()` method is better than `df.merge()` method

```
df2.rename(columns={'station':'COL1.'},inplace=True)
df1.set_index(['COL1.','month'],inplace=True)
df2.set_index(['COL1.','month'],inplace=True)
df2.join(df1)
```

Comment: and how it is better?can you please tell